# Computing the derivative of an integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

There are similar questions on the same topic, yet I could not figure out why the following equation (taken from an economics solution manual) holds:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial C(i,j)} \int_0^1P(j)\cdot C(i,j)\ \mathrm{d}j =P(j)
$$

where no further information about the functions $P(j), C(i,j)$ is given (though continuity and differentiability could be assumed if needed).

I guess the more general statement that I do not see is something like:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f(x)}\int_0^1g(f(x))\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\partial g(f(x))}{\partial f(x)}
$$

which looks somewhat wrong to me...

Any help greatly appreciated. I hope I have posted sufficient information to make this question actually sensible/answerable.

Comment: Is that really just $P(j)$ on the right-hand side of the equation? So the $j$ has somehow become a free variable?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is stated. I know that $ \int_0^1 P(j)C(i,j)\mathrm{d}j$ shouldn't depend on $j$ any more, but I thought maybe it appears on the RHS because we are taking the derivative w.r.t. $C(i,\mathbf{j})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the more general formulation would be something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_a^b f(x,y) \,dx = \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) \,dx$. Changing the variable of integration from $x$ to $j$ and taking $y = C(i,j)$, $a = 0$, and $b = 1$, I get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial C(i,j)} \int_0^1 P(j) \cdot C(i,j) \,dx = \int_0^1 P(j) \,dj.$$
That avoids having a free variable spring apparently from nowhere, but I don't know where it leaves you with respect to the rest of the part of the manual that deals with this formula.

Another thing that I might think to do when faced with an "equation" like this is to check the left-hand side.  Sometimes people forget to take the integration symbols away when they start setting up equations involving the integrand.  Is it possible the authors really meant the following?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial C(i,j)}  P(j) \cdot C(i,j) = \ P(j) .$$

Comment: Well but in the problem above, the variable with respect to which we are differentiating, $C(i,j)$, also depends on the variable with respect to which we are taking the integral, $j$. In your notation, we would have $y(x)$ rather than simply $y$. Does this not make a difference?

Comment: If it were $\frac{d}{dC(i,j)}$ then it certainly would matter that $P(j)$ might vary with $C(i,j)$, and the right-hand expression would be even more complicated.  But the notation was $\frac{\partial}{\partial C(i,j)}$, which is a partial derivative.